# Is it possible to execute a python(django) function immediately on vs code?

Tags: python, django, methods, visual-studio-code, immediate-window

I want to execute a python function in vs code directly when I set a breakpoint when debugging. Just like Immediate window on Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can set the break-point and in *Debug* tab add configuration *Django*. And then run debugging.
Like this:[image: VS code screenshot, debug configuration]

Hope this will help!